# Can I run PowerShell script of version 4.0 on windows server with powershell script version 2.0

Tags: powershell

Can I run PowerShell script of version 4.0 on windows server with powershell script version 2.0?
I have developed script using PowerShell version 4.0 on local server. Now I want to test this script on Development Windows server installed with PowerShell version 2.0. Can this script of 4.0 works in Dev server with script version 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you are using features, cmdlets, etc. that were available in version 2.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which cmdlets, functions and operators you are using - we cannot say for sure.

A PowerShell script file (*.ps1) will attempt to execute on any version of PowerShell.  Whether it works or not depends on what is referenced within it.

Here is a list of stuff introduced in PowerShell Versions that were either not present or worked differently in earlier versions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh857339.aspx

If you reference anything in this list that isnt supported, you will need to find alternative ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

you can actually run any PowerShell script on any system which has PowerShell installed, except if one of the two following conditions are true:

- Your ExecutionPolicy isn't set up properly and you can't run any script, e.g when it's set to "AllSigned" and your scripts aren't signed
- The Author of the script set a `#requires` statement like `#requires -version 4` then you can only run the script in the specific version or higher.

otherwise running any script should be possible, but if the author of the script used cmdlets, parameters or aliases which weren't available on a earlier versions, it could be that the script doesn't do what you want and throw/write an error. thats why the author should always set a `#requires` statement